# Windows xp/ Windows 7 copy command behavior

Tags: windows, backup

We have a folder to which a lot of people copy files. Instead of over writing the existing file on the folder, I would like to rename the original file first, and then copy the new file.

Example: If I copy a file `myFile.txt` (which is already present in the folder), it should save the existing file as `myFile_backup.txt` and copy the new file as `myFile.txt`.

Is this possible?

Comment: What would happen the following time the back up run - would you want to add a number for each time the back up run (eg myFile01.txt, myFile02.txt) - you will end up with a massive folder.

Comment: Hi Dave,  
Thanks a lot for your response.  I just need to have one backup version.  At any instance after the 1st copy, I will only have myFile.txt and myFile_backup.txt.

Thanks!

Comment: So, on the third time the back up runs (where you have myFile and myFile_backup) what happens. Does myFile overwrite myFile_backup ?

Comment: Yes.  myFile overwrites myFile_backup.  I just want to have one previous version of the file as a backup.  

Also, is this function valid only for a session?  When I exit and comeback, it tells me copyFileToFolder does not exist.  I am very new to this thing so sorry for asking such basic questions.

Comment: The default behavior for Windows 7 is to prompt the user what to do when a file with the same name appears in a folder being copied to.  My suggestion is to inform everyone of this behavior.

Comment: Thanks Ram.  But how do I override the default behaviour.  All it asks is copy and replace or dont copy.  How do I handle my scenario - as it is a critical folder and I need to have a backup of anything that is copied.

Comment: Windows 7 offers a 3rd option, namely *Copy, but keep both files*.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* possible, however you will need to create a batch file (could be placed inside this folder you mention) that people would *drag-and-drop* file onto, which will do the following:

1. Gets the drag-and-dropped file as an argument/parameter that the batch file can use.
2. Checks for files with the same name as the dropped file
3. If the *dropped* file's name is unique, then save the file
4. If the *dropped* file is *not* unique, then first rename the conflicting file to *filename_backup.ext*, then save the file

Doing the above, you will achieve what you are looking for. Of course this means you will have to educate/force all users of that folder to *always* drag-and-drop files onto this special batch file.

You could place this batch file at the root of a folder and then save the actual files to another sub-folder so users will immediately notice that they have to drop the file onto the batch file.